# iOS Instagram login get Instagram user id?

Tags: ios, authentication, instagram

I am writing an iOS app that needs to do some basic work against the "Instagram API". To login a user I simply hit the "[URL](https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%3Cmy_client_id%3E&redirect_uri=%3Credirect%20URI%3E&response_type=token)":

I do this through a web view. I am able to login the user and get the access token from "Instagram".

So my question is:

I want to be able to know the "Instagram userId" of the user I just logged in.

How can I get the user id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `user_id` is in the first part of `access_token`

xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
user_id = access_token.split(".")[0];
```

Comment: this is the quickest way. the first part of the token before the first period is the Instagram user id. Thank you. The other solution I posted works too, but, this one is faster obviously.

Answer (score 0):

just enter your user name then user id will display

http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id

Comment: The only place where the user enters the username is in the web view that logs the user in through the instagram login page. I don't have the username. The only thing I get back is this: http://www.asite.com/#access_token=<the token returned from instagram>. So I am not sure how to use this answer to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: this is for getting a particullar userid.is your answer correct?

Comment: yes, by calling the url in my answer I can now get the user id and more in one call. It basically returns userId, username etc... so, basic user info including the id, simply by providing the token in the url I got during the login using the web view.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out to be quite simple, I simply didn't figure out how until now. So once the user logs in through the web view the web view returns the access_token. With that I can call this GET:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self?access_token="the access token I just got from the login"
```

So, all I have to do is use "self" in the url and that combined with the access token will return the user object which contains the username and more.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.otzberg.net/iguserid/

look down the web and you can look about the Instagram User ID Finder, and you should find by yoursef, It's so easy to find.

```
* Open Google Chrome and access your Instagram Profile Page, e.g. Lufthansa Instagram Page
* Open the Developer Tools (F12 on Windows; ⌥+⌘+i on OS X)
* Click the Console Option
* At the little command prompt enter:   window._sharedData.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].user.id   and hit enter
* If you get an error, reload the page and try again
* Until Instagram Changes their page, this will output your User-ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find an instagram user ID from a username is: https://www.thekeygram.com/find-instagram-user-id/. Works for me every time. And they always keep it updated to support the latest instagram api updates (at least from my experience)